# Chronometer keeps counting even when the phone is off ,there isn't internet connection,not change if another time/date is set by the phone settings

Tags: java, android

I have implemented an android acitivty containing a chronometer :

```
Chronometer c1;
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    c1=(Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("name_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=prefs.edit();

}




private long timechrono=0L;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    timechrono = prefs.getLong("timechrono", 0L);//time start chrono from 1 january 1970

    long timereboot = 0L;//time activity not work

    if (timechrono > 0) {
        timereboot = currentTimeMillis() - timechrono;
        c1.setBase(elapsedRealtime()-timereboot);

    } else {
        c1.setBase(elapsedRealtime());

    }

    if (timechrono == 0){

        timechrono = currentTimeMillis();//when chrono start
        editor.putLong("timechrono", timechrono); //tempo di conteggio del chronometro dal 1 gennaio 1970
    }

    c1.start();



}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    c1.stop();
    editor.commit();

}
```

This code works well, but **when user change data or time from setting on the phone, the chrono change**.

This because i use currentTimeMillis() which is affected by these changes,
But **if I use methods like System.nano**, when the user turns off the phone, **restarting time does not count**(Because it does not count since January 1, 1970).

**I would like a chronometer keeps counting even when the phone is off ,there isn't internet connection and that it would not change if another time/date is set by the phone settings**

I just need to find an alternative to currentTimeMillis(), but that does not change if the user changes manually time/date from setting on phone.

thank you all.

Comment: [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) may be what you're looking for

Comment: i read that In android this features isn't support (only in api 26) (java8)